# Prevent negative numbers in ionic ion-input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an numbers input field in my app and even tho I have prevented the numbers from going to negative values if I click fast enough it sometimes still happens. And the user can still type in the "-"(minus) character and thus causing an error... How can I make the input ignore the "-" character and not go lower than 0.

I have implemented some solutions from SO that I found but still I can input negative numbers...

here is my HTML code:

```
<ion-item lines="none" slot="end">
  <ion-icon color="vigros" name="remove-circle" (click)="decrementQty(product)"></ion-icon>
  <ion-input (keyup)="_keyUp($event)" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" [(ngModel)]="product.qty" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"></ion-input>
  <ion-icon color="vigros" name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(product)"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

and here is the JS(Typescript) code: I found this in one of the answers on here:

```
  _keyUp(event: any) {
    const pattern = /[0-9\+\ ]/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.key);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }}
```

Anything else I can change to prevent the user to type in negative numbers and to prevent the numbers going lower than 0?

Comment: You can use the `ionInput` event. The documentation provides [an example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#filtering-user-input).